# nodeJS cannot see local path when using API endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I have the code below that runs fine when run in a standalone file. But when I try to use it in my API endpoint and send a request with the postman, it can't seem to work.

I can't understand why. I also have the same issue when trying to write an excel file with the same API endpoint. If I specify a path, it won't find it. If I just use the filename, it will write fine in the current directory.

What am I missing? the code below is from when I use it in a standalone file. If I use it inside this route below, it won't work.

```
exports.download_excel = async (req, res) => {....
```

full code below

```
// modules import
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const csv = require('@fast-csv/parse');
const { forEach } = require('p-iteration');

// const path = '../csv/';
const casesBO = [];


const readCSVFiles = async function() {
  try {
    const allLocalFiles = path.join('csv/');
    const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
    await readDir(allLocalFiles, async function(err, file) {
      forEach(file, async item => {
        fs.createReadStream('csv/' + item)
          .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true, delimiter: ';' }))
          .on('error', error => console.error(error))
          .on('data', async row => {
            if (row['[REGION2]'] !== 'FR') {
              casesBO.push(row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']);
              console.log(
                `${row['[AGENT]']} is ${row['[REGION2]']} and case = ${
                  row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']
                }`
              );
            }
          })
          .on('end', async rowCount => {});
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `await`ing readDir, but you are also giving it a callback function. You can't both `await` a Promise and also give it a callback. For that matter, Promises don't take a callback as argument at all.

Also you are writing `async` everywhere, this is useless for functions that don't await anything inside.

```
const readCSVFiles = async function () {
    try {
        const allLocalFiles = path.join('csv/');
        const readDir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);

        const files = await readDir(allLocalFiles);

        for (let file of files) {

            fs.createReadStream('csv/' + file)
                .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true, delimiter: ';' }))
                .on('error', error => console.error(error))
                .on('data', row => {
                    if (row['[REGION2]'] !== 'FR') {
                        casesBO.push(row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']);
                        console.log(
                            `${row['[AGENT]']} is ${row['[REGION2]']} and case = ${row['[CALLERNO_EMAIL_SOCIAL]']
                            }`
                        );
                    }
                })
                .on('end', rowCount => { });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still new at programming and your answer helped me a lot. I had figured out that i needed to add ___dirname, before the path for it to work but then it seemed that everything would stall when i tried to run it. With your code everything worked smoothly.